# What does Chantor's Talon means?

Tags: cinema, interjections

I was watching the movie Onward (2020), at 48:07, then Ian hear the cops' siren, he exclaims:

> Chantor's Talon! Cops!

What does "Chantor's Talon" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You know *Onward* is fictional, right?  "Chantor's Talon" is some made-up profanity for that culture.  Is there any further meaning?  Without seeing the movie I can only guess ... Perhaps "Chantor" is a god or demon of theirs, and (being not very cultured) Ian swears on his talon.